# How to merge excel rows based on date and another category

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Which is an excel formula I can use to combine rows together based on the same category and same month with the updated sum of the two numbers?

Comment: You need `UNIQUE()` then `SUMIFS()` function. What output do you expect from given data. Also post data as text table so that we can copy.

Comment: You are trying to recreate a pivot table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula-based alternative for O365:

`=LET(ζ,SORT(UNIQUE(A2:B25),{1,2}),CHOOSE({1,1,2},ζ,SUMIFS(C2:C25,A2:A25,INDEX(ζ,,1),B2:B25,INDEX(ζ,,2))))`

Answer (score 1):

I have created a simple pivot table, based on entries, similar like yours. This is what it looks like:

[image]

(The "Months" is added by Excel itself)